# Compare hours with google-script

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new in the world of programming: D and I have a doubt about the comparison of hours.

I have a sheet with the following information

```
   Name | Time out | Time in |
   nam_1  10:00:00
   nam_2  09:00:00
```

Time out hours have been entered using this code:

```
var start = Utilities.formatDate (new Date (), "Europe / Berlin", "HH: mm: ss");

sheet.appendRow([name, start]);
```

What I would like to try is:

```
var time_in = "13:00:00";
   if time out> 13:00:00:
      sheet.getRange(j+1, 2).setValue(time_in);
```

The problem is that I do not know exactly how to do it. What I have tried for now is:

```
function getTimeFromDateStartUserInput(date) { 
    return Utilities.formatDate(date, "Europe/Berlin", "HH:mm:ss");
}
function insertTimeIn(){
   var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("MySheet");
   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.open(file.next());
   var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   if(sheet!=null){
      var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
      var values = dataRange.getValues();
      var time_in = new Date ('30/12/1899 17:00:00');
      time_in.setHours(13,0,0,0);
      var inFormated = getTimeFromDate(time_in);
      for(var i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
         if(values[i][1]>=inFormated && values[i][2]=""){
            sheet.getRange(j+1, 2).setValue(time_in);
      }else{
           sheet.getRange(j+1, 2).setValue("Nop");
      }

   }
}
```

However, I have not achieved anything with that code.

I think the problem may be that any entry in the "Time out" column has this design: Sat Dec 30 14:51:22 GMT + 01: 00 1899.

Therefore I think it does not work since I am comparing an hour with a complete Date object.

The logical thing I think it would be to call the function getTimeFromDateStartUserInput for all the input of values[i][1] but I do not know how to do it.

Could someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is my guess at what you are trying to do.  It doesn't work because it still contains errors.  I commented on a few of them but I can't fix them because it's still not clear what you are trying to do..

```
function insertTimeIn(){
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('SpreadsheetName');
  var n=0;
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var file=files.next();
  }
  if(++n>1){
    throw("Error: There is more than one file with that name in function insertTimeIn");
    return;
  }
  if(file.getMimeType()==MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS){
    var doc=SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    var sheet=doc.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    if(sheet!=null){
      var dataRange=sheet.getDataRange();
      var values=dataRange.getValues();
      var time_in=new Date(1899,11,30,13,0,0);
      var inFormated=Utilities.formatDate(time_in, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss");//it returns a string not a date
      for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
        if(values[i][1]>=inFormated && values[i][2]=""){//informated is a string not a date so greater than doesn't really make much sense here.
          sheet.getRange(j+1, 2).setValue(time_in);//j is undefined
        }else{
          sheet.getRange(j+1, 2).setValue("Nop");//again j is undefined
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer might be to auto convert the initial timestamp to the current date. I'm not entirely sure what the use of your sheet is going to be but I use a sheet for time entry and use the function onEdit() to verify that the user put the dateTime in correctly.

```js
    function onEdit(){
if(cell.getValue() instanceof Date === true){
      if(cell.getValue().getFullYear()<2018 ){
      formatDate();
      }  
     }
    }


    function formatDate() {
    var timeValue, cell,hour,minute,time,row,dateObj,month,day,year,newDate
      cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell()
      timeValue = cell.getValue()
      hour = timeValue.getHours()
      minute = timeValue.getMinutes() < 10? '0'+timeValue.getMinutes(): timeValue.getMinutes();
      time = hour+":"+minute
      row = cell.getRow()
      dateObj = new Date();
      month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
      day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
      year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

    newDate = month + "/" + day + " "+ time; // formatted dateTimestamp to replace timestamp with

    cell.setValue(newDate)
    }
```

Let me know if that works for you. In my application, the onEdit function checks the active cell and continues if the entered value is a dateTime. If it is, it check what year the date is (time values alone are automatically 12/30/1899 and therefore throw wild numbers out when getting durations between a dateTimestamp and a timestamp with no date.